# QGIS - Value relation relative to other field

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, valuerelation

I've been trying to search for a solution for this to no avail.

I have a value relation set up and want another field connected and relative to this.

Example:
Field 1 (Value 1)
Field 2 (Value 2)

Value 1.1 = Value 2.1
Value 1.2 = Value 2.2
And so on.

So if i add Value 1.1 to field 1 i want it to automatically add Value 2.1 to field 2.

Field 2 does not need to be editable so it only needs to go one way so to speak.

Is there a solution for this?

EDIT:
Clarification what i want to do.
The actual values i want to use are tree species names.
If "Acer platanoides" is added to field 1 i want "Maple" in field 2.
I have a value relation set up with the species name but want the common name to be added automatically as well. Preferably in a separate field.

Comment: Could you please edit your question with the software you are using?

Comment: Of course, sorry about that! Done!

Comment: Your question lacks details, but it sounds like you could make use of a [virtual field](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#creating-a-virtual-field)

Comment: Are Field 1 & Field 2 numeric fields? Otherwise, @Cushen's proposed code for the virtual field won't work.

Comment: No, the fields are not numeric values im afraid. I chose to use value wording because i thought it would make it more understandable, but maybe i just made it confusing. I will update my question with clarification!

Comment: I've amended the answer to allow for strings, in that scenario we can use CASE expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a Virtual Field to do this.
Create Field 2 as a **virtual field** and with an expression.
In the 'Maple' example above we want to turn a string into another based on the Field1 value. For this we can use a [CASE Expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/expression.html#some-use-cases-of-expressions) such as:

```
CASE 
WHEN "FIELD1" = 'Acer platanoides' THEN 'Maple'
WHEN "FIELD1" = 'Quercus alba' THEN 'White Oak'
END
```

As values are added or edited to Field1 Field2 will update once a save is made. We can add as many WHEN checks to the CASE as we need.

*In my example below Field1 has the name 'HubDist' & we are dealing with numbers not strings*

[image: example image]